# Accidentally Deleted ODBC Driver in the Registry

Tags: oracle, odbc, windows-server-2003

I accidentally deleted the registry entry for the ODBC driver when uninstalling Oracle and I would like to know how to recover it.  The ODBC item no longer appears in the **Create New Data Source** window when you select to Add a Data Source in the **ODBC Data Source Administrator** under User DSN or System DSN.

I guess I need to re-install the ODBC Oracle Driver?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to re-install the Oracle client along with the ODBC driver.

If you go to OTN to [download the 11.2 database](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/index.html) and click on the "See All" option for the appropriate version of Windows (either 32- or 64-bit), there should be an option to download a client-only install (though this is a ~600 MB download).  That will let you install the full Oracle client and the Oracle ODBC driver (you may want to do a custom install to make sure that the ODBC driver is selected-- there are various client install options that don't install the ODBC driver).

It should also be possible to download the [Oracle Instant Client](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index-097480.html)-- you'll need the basic package and the ODBC package.  The Instant Client, though, requires a bit more manual configuration.  It is more common to have the Instant Client bundled with the installer for an application that is being installed on a server so that the application can install its own version of the Oracle client.